# turn on furnace blower with temp sensor

Tags: thermostat, furnace, fireplace

I have a wood stove in my finished basement.   I am looking for a way to turn on the blower fan of my furnace once the temperature in the basement reaches a certain setting like 75 degrees, that is warmer than the rest of the house, and use the fan to circulate the heat to the rest of the house since a main intake is down there.   My current setup is that I have heat and no AC.   My current thermostat is a Nest Gen 1 and it is upstairs.   It is only wired to control the heat and not the fan.   The fan is controlled by a toggle switch on the side of the unit.  I can do this now but it is manual.  Is there a setup that will allow me to control the fan, triggered by a downstairs temperature setting, while still allowing the upstairs thermostat to kick in when needed?   The downstairs would essentially function in the same way as AC, kicking on when it got too hot.   Would it be possible to have a second thermostat control the AC portion of the furnace?  In the picture the green and red wire are coming from the fan toggle switch and the white and red are coming from the thermostat.  The model of the furnace is a Trane G40UH-36B-090-15
[image]

Comment: the furnace may have an option to turn on the fan remotely, but sadly, we have no information about your furnace

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Without more info, any answer is going to be "Maybe...". Would you add info about your furnace (make, model, etc)?

Comment: You could add a temp switch down stairs in parallel with your existing thermostat if either stat turns on the system will run.